# Grails <where> returns DetachedCriteria with all entries

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

```
Domain.where {
    1 == 0
}.count()
```

This returned all the elements of the domain class. The more general case:

```
Domain.where {
    false
}.count()
```

Will return all elements; if I use one of the fields and make a false condition, the result is as expected.

My question is why does this happen (the first case) ? If it is a too naive question, please just suggest some reading material. Thanks!

The version of grails that I use is 2.3.6 (it may be different in newer versions?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but here is an explanation (maybe a bit general because of that :).

What you pass to the `where` method is actually a DSL for specifying SQL criterias, it just uses normal Groovy syntax to pretend to be more natural. But when you do `someProperty != 5 && someOtherProperty == 6` that is not evaluated directly, but transformed to end up in an SQL query as `select * from Domain where some_property != 5 and some_other_property = 6`.

Since you are not passing any reference to a property in your criteria (`1 == 0`), it gets ignored by the detached criteria DSL evaluator, thus returning the result of `select * from domain`. You can try to do for example `id != id` to see how you get an empty list as the result. If you again examine the resulting query, you'll see that a `where id<>id` is included.

You can learn more about the `where` method: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries

Bear in mind that what you pass to the `where` method is a `Closure`, so the code inside is not executed upfront, and is not necessarily evaluated in the context where it was declared. You can [learn more about Groovy Closures](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html). Also about [creating DSLs with Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html), though is a bit of an advanced topic.

(I simplified the SQL queries to make them more undestandable, if you activate the query log of Hibernate or MySQL/other DB you are using, you'll see they are bigger).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The third paragraph was exactly the situation with which I have been confronting yesterday! I had suspected something similar, but I was not sure if it made sense (at the time). I had solved this by changing the criteria in there `where` to something like `id<0` (just to check if it does give the expected results); your explanation solved/explained the question I had. Thanks again!

Comment: I just needed to return a `DetachedCriteria<Domain>` with no elements, and my initial thoughts were that if I would have a condition inside the closure that is `false` then it would not give me anything (disregarding any reference to properties of the domain class)

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, for that you need a condition that is false - but false when applied to the rows contained in the database :), exactly as the one you provided in your commend (`id < 0`) .

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate Deigote's explanation, here's a ***very crude*** implementation of a WHERE query builder (actually just the WHERE clause) using the [criteria criteria](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/grails/gorm/DetachedCriteria.groovy) format:

```
class WhereBuilder {
    def conditions = []

    def eq(column, value) {
        conditions << [
            column: column, 
            operator: '=', 
            value: value]
    }

    def ne(column, value) {
        conditions << [
            column: column, 
            operator: '!=', 
            value: value]
    }

    String toString() {
        'WHERE ' << 
            conditions.collect { 
                "${it.column} ${it.operator} '${it.value}'"
            }.join(' AND ')
    }
}

def builder = new WhereBuilder()
builder.with {
    1 == 0
    false    
    eq 'firstName', 'John'
    ne 'lastName', 'Smith'
}

assert builder.toString() == "WHERE firstName = 'John' AND lastName != 'Smith'"
```

As you can see, the expressions *1 == 0* and *false* have no effect.